# pandas apply updates inplace but returns None

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I do not understand this apply behavior .. pandas apply updates  inplace but returns None

```
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>df_test = pd.Series({0: {'A', 'E'},
                     1: {'A', 'C', 'E', 'S'},
                     2: {'A', 'C', 'E'},
                     3: {'A', 'C', 'E', 'S'},
                     4: {'A', 'E'}})
>>>df_test
0          {A, E}
1    {A, S, E, C}
2       {A, C, E}
3    {A, S, E, C}
4          {A, E}
dtype: object

>>>df_test.apply(lambda x: x.add("X"))
0    None
1    None
2    None
3    None
4    None
dtype: object
```

but,

```
>>>df_test
0          {A, X, E}
1    {A, X, S, E, C}
2       {A, X, C, E}
3    {A, X, S, E, C}
4          {A, X, E}
dtype: object
```

so df_test is updated. but then if I do this:

```
>>> df_test = df_test.apply(lambda x: x.add("X"))
>>> df_test
0    None
1    None
2    None
3    None
4    None
dtype: object
```

what is the explanation for thisbehavior -  the apply is updating the dataframe in place but returned type is None.

Comment: Adding to a set doesn't return a copy of the set, it returns None, and modifies the set in place.

Comment: This is **nothing to do with** Pandas. It has to do with the built-in `set` type.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75851273

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to a **`set`** is an in-place operation that returns `None`, so while the Series will be updated, the copy returned from **`apply`** will have `None` set in every row.

If you really want to view the results when you call apply, instead of adding to the set, you could use the union of two sets to get your desired results:

```
df_test.apply(lambda x: x | {'X'})

0          {A, X, E}
1    {A, X, E, C, S}
2       {A, X, E, C}
3    {A, X, E, C, S}
4          {A, X, E}
```

Which does not modify the original Series:

```
df_test   

0          {A, E}  
1    {A, E, C, S}  
2       {A, E, C}  
3    {A, E, C, S}  
4          {A, E}
```

Comment: nice. may be this is my ignorance, but I have never come across this usage of pipe in python for sets

Answer (score 1):

You operate on python sets inside you apply function.  Using add is an in place operation on that set, and it (the add function) returns None.
To do what you want, you can do something like:

```
df_test = df_test.apply(lambda x: x |{"X"})
```

This will return a new set, which is the original set plus X, för each row.